# How to find eigenvectors of a matrix given only eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Given a $3\times 3$ matrix with eigen values $3,0,-1$, are their associated
> eigen vectors $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ orthogonal to each other?

My thought process is that we need to find three possible eigen vectors, then test whether they're orthogonal. However how would I go about reverse engineering the eigen vectors? Or am I going about the problem wrong? For some reason I'm having a hard time understand how I would do that without being given a matrix.

Comment: How would you make up matrices given only the eigenvalues? If you specify the eigenvectors, can you find the matrix?

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I'm not sure how I should specify the eigenvectors in this case. The way I learned to do it was through using the A·v=λ·v equation, so I'm feeling lost without A haha

Comment: Hint: Change of basis formula.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with that but it looks promising for this... I'm not sure if I'm understanding the formula correctly, but wouldn't I need to know the actual values of the vectors or a matrix to plugin to the formula?

Comment: As José suggested, you can choose any basis you want for the three eigenvectors.

Comment: The answer is "not necessarily". Was this the actual question with no other information?

Answer (score 1):

Fix any non-orthogonal basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, such has, say $\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Now, take the matrix $A$ of the linear map from $F^3$ into itself (where $F$ is the field with which you are working) which maps $v_1$ into $3v_1$, $v_2$ into $0$, and $v_3$ into $-v_3$. And you're done: the eigenvalues of $A$ are $3$, $0$, and $-1$ and its eigenvectors are not orthogonal.

In this case, you have$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with linear mapping in this context, I was trying to read more about it but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Could you explain the mapping part and how you wind up with those particular values for the vector A? Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: In the first place, $A$ is not a vector; it's a matrix. And I considered the matrix$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},$$whose columns are the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$. Then, I defined$$A=P\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.$$Since it is defined this way, I know that $A.v_3=3v_3$, that $A.v_2=0$, and that $A.v_3=-v_3$.

Answer (score 0):

With any set of real eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are orthogonal iff the matrix is **Hermitian** -- meaning, each $(i,j)$ element is the complex conjugate of the $(j,i)$ element.

Thus the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \color{blue}{1+i\sqrt3} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \color{brown}{1-i\sqrt3} & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

with eigenvalues $3,0,-1$ will have orthogonal rigenvectors because the $\{(i,j),(j,i)\}$ pairs (like the blue and brown elements above) are all complex conjugates. By contrast the matrix

$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \color{brown}{4} & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

whose eigenvalues are also $3,0,-1$ does not have orthogonal eigenvectors; the blue and brown elements are not complex conjugates.